# How to enable grunt-sass sourceComments with bourbon

Tags: sass, gruntjs, comments, bourbon

I'm trying to get source comments in my output CSS. I'm using foundation framework and compiling with Grunt and Bourbon. I've tried setting `sourceComments` to `true` in `options`, but it hasn't worked yet. I'm using `grunt-sass`, not `grunt-contrib-sass`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use **grunt-contrib-sass** , all **contrib** tasks has a constantly update and good community.

if you use **grunt-contib-sass** just use like that:

```
sass.dev = {
        options: { 
        style: "expanded", 
        lineNumber: true,
        update:true
        }
};
```

Comment: I like your recommendation, but unfortunately I work with a team that I'd have to run that by first. I've resorted to using `sourceMap`, which gets me most of the way there.

Comment: I understand, habbits in a company is a devil, do you have like a group in your company where you can send like plugins changes, language changes? indention changes so you can show the benefits why the company should move?